# Jquery .append() stacks the boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

Hey there my question is why dose the Jquery Function `append()` stacks my blue boxes i want that they dont break up that they are in one line.

Thats how i add my blue boxes

```
    for(var i = 1;i <= round;i++){
                          $('#items').append(" <li id='item"+i+"' > <img id='img"+i+"' 
 src='http://s1.directupload.net/images/131110/24huoqrm.png'></img></li>");
 // this is the html blue box.

                           }
```

And here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLyyR/11/)

Comment: Stacks the blue boxes? Only thing that looks wrong to me is the position of the black boxes

Comment: yeah this will be a news ticker where news letters slide from left to right in "Blue Boxes" but the boxes are orientating on the size of the gray "content box /#tickercontainer" so they break and stack under each other. 
sry for bad explanaiton dont know it better in english.

Comment: i only want 1 bluebox each layer

Comment: If we set  width: 2700px;  for class "tickercontainer" in css, all blue boxes appear in a single line. Is it what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Yes but without changing the size of the "tickercontainer" it should just overflow

Comment: I'm guessing OP doesn't want to use a static width, but wants to grow the container depending on the child elements added.